# how long is the duration of a rolling upgrade

Tags: elasticsearch

According to this rolling upgrade instructions, it says

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rolling-upgrades.html

"Running multiple versions of Elasticsearch in the same cluster beyond the duration of an upgrade is not supported"

Does anyone know how long is the duration?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It means that Elasticsearch support running multiple versions of itself on the cluster only during upgrade process. After upgrade is done you should decide which version you want to run and shutdown the other.